# Execute injected script element after it has been loaded dynamically

Tags: javascript, ajax

I make an ajax request that injects a script node in my head or body element like this:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

    this._client.get('/getFragment', (responseText) => {
        const obj = JSON.parse(responseText);
        const scriptTag = document.createElement('template');
        scriptTag.innerHTML = obj.fragment;

        document.body.appendChild(scriptTag.content);
    });
});
```

The issue now is that the script is injected into the DOM, but as this JS script calls another external URL I can see in the network monitor that the URL of the script is not called/executed. How can make sure that the script tag is executed after I injected it into the DOM?

The fragment that I would like to inject is this one:

```
<script id="mcjs">!function(c,h,i,m,p){m=c.createElement(h),p=c.getElementsByTagName(h)[0],m.async=1,m.src=i,p.parentNode.insertBefore(m,p)}(document,"script","https://chimpstatic.com/mcjs-connected/js/users/1f.js");</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you are asking, but I believe the the problem is that you are creating a `template` element, and browsers usually doesn't execute the content of those. Try using `document.createElement('div')` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not what I meant. When I do this, I inject this into my head `<div><script id="mcjs">` ... I just want to insert my string, which is `<script>...` as a node in the `<head>` and the browser should execute it. Currently it's injected, but the browser does not execute it after injection...

Comment: @Torben I think that is exactly what I said: Don't use 'template', use 'div'.